# How to add 2FA in Django and DRF

Tags: python, django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I am not sure how to add 2FA to my django project and DRF ?
I will eventually connect this DRF with react and redux as the frontend.

Here is my Django side:

Models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

My Django api serializer

```
# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]

        })


# Check token and send back what user is associated with that token
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

My Django urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from knox import views as knox_views
from accounts.api.views import LoginAPI, UserAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
    path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),
```

My django views:

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken

from accounts.api.serializers import LoginSerializer, UserSerializer


# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]

        })


# Check token and send back what user is associated with that token
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: Try [**django-oauth-toolkit**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth-toolkit) module